# In jenkins I configured multiple svn Modules ，how to select only one of them based on the parameters

Tags: jenkins, svn, jenkins-plugins

In jenkins, I have configured multiple svn modules in a certain job. Different modules correspond to different svn repositories, and their account passwords are different. Only one of the repositories will be used for each build. I should How to configure on jenkins? ?

Answer (score 0):

You can add multiple SVN repositories to Jenkins with different accounts.

```
Manage Jenkins --> Configure System --> SubVersion (SVN)
```

In this section you can use **`"Add"`** button to add multiple repository with different settings and accounts. Then you can select each environment in your job's configuration as you wish.